# When did British and American English split on "in future" vs. "in the future"?

Tags: etymology, american-english, british-english

I'm curious if it's possible to document roughly when the split happened, and also curious whether British or American usage diverged.

Comment: This question, unlike the marked duplicate, asks about the history of these phrases, not their meaning; voting to reopen.

Comment: @Nathaniel thanks... some half-hearted efforts in the review queue going on here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at this [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+the+future_NOUN%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cin+future_NOUN%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cin+the+future_NOUN%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Cin+future_NOUN%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20future_NOUN%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20future_NOUN%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20future_NOUN%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20future_NOUN%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0), you see that both Brits and Americans used to use *"in future"*, and this expression is being replaced by *"in the future"* both places. It's just that in the U.S., the replacement is now almost complete while in the U.K. it is still happening.

When did this split happen? The replacement was quite gradual, so it's hard to narrow it down to something shorter than "the last half of the 19th century".

Comment: could you explain the search tags you used? didn't know any such things were available on ngrams. is there a reference page?

Comment: There's a [reference page](https://books.google.com/ngrams/info). The search tags future_NOUN, to eliminate uses of future as an adjective (i.e., *in future centuries,* etc.), which are still very common in the U.S. And :eng_us_2012, :eng_gb_2012, to narrow it down to American and British sources. (I believe this last piece has some misclassification, so the frequency of *in future* is probably even lower in the U.S. than is indicated by the Ngram.)

Comment: also, perhaps you can interpret the results before 1800 better? it looks to me like neither phrase was in widespread usage before 1800 or so... or is that just a reflection of data quality?

Comment: The data quality gets fairly bad before 1800, but if you change the start date, it looks like *in future* started being used around 1750, and *in the future* started slightly later in the U.S.

Comment: Actually, looking at usages of *in the future* before 1800 in Google Books, they seem mostly to be talking about grammar (i.e., *future* means *future tense*). So I'd guess that *in the future* didn't start replacing *in future* until the early 19th century.

Comment: so you'd say "in future" came first before eventually being replaced in the US by "in the future", which is now spreading everywhere else?

Comment: @PeterShor I am wondering if this falls into the same category as *in hospital v in the hospital*, *in prison v in the prison*. The article is dropped in Britain where the place amounts to a state or condition. Similarly it is dropped where *future* is a state or context rather than an actual time.